# JMeter ForEach Controller overriding Output variable name?

Tags: jmeter

When using JMeter ForEach Controller in a Thread Group I defined a variable start index such as: `${startFrom}` which is different per thread and output variable name as `currentFile`. It is followed by a logging sampler and I can see that `startFrom` is passed as expected and different for each thread but ALL threads have the same `currentFile`.

I expected that each thread would have a different `currentFile` since they should start from different index. What am I doing wrong and how can I get each thread to have the correct `currentFile`?

-EDIT-

What I am trying to do is actually the following: fetch all files from FTP in one thread, then split files into batches so each thread pulls equal amount of those files I fetched in that one thread. I will add a short edit showing my problem.

Example showing this problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jmeterTestPlan version="1.2" properties="5.0" jmeter="5.0 r1840935">
  <hashTree>
    <TestPlan guiclass="TestPlanGui" testclass="TestPlan" testname="Test Plan" enabled="true">
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.comments"></stringProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.functional_mode">false</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.serialize_threadgroups">true</boolProp>
      <elementProp name="TestPlan.user_defined_variables" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
        <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
      </elementProp>
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.user_define_classpath"></stringProp>
    </TestPlan>
    <hashTree>
      <ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="FTP Fetch" enabled="true">
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
        <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="LoopController.loops">1</stringProp>
        </elementProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">1</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">1</stringProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.delay"></stringProp>
      </ThreadGroup>
      <hashTree>
        <JSR223Sampler guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="JSR223Sampler" testname="Generate FTP dummy files" enabled="true">
          <stringProp name="cacheKey">true</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="filename"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="parameters"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="script">def range = 1..10
for (n in range) {
    props.put(&apos;file_&apos; + n, String.valueOf(n))
}
</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="scriptLanguage">groovy</stringProp>
        </JSR223Sampler>
        <hashTree/>
      </hashTree>
      <ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="FTP pull" enabled="true">
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
        <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="LoopController.loops">1</stringProp>
        </elementProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">5</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">1</stringProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.delay"></stringProp>
      </ThreadGroup>
      <hashTree>
        <JSR223Sampler guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="JSR223Sampler" testname="Copy from props to vars for visibility in FTP requests" enabled="true">
          <stringProp name="TestPlan.comments">Not really used in this example, but still...</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="scriptLanguage">groovy</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="parameters"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="filename"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="cacheKey">true</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="script">def range = 1..10
for (n in range) {
    vars.put(&apos;file_&apos; + n, props.get(&apos;file_&apos; + n))
    log.info(&apos;Copied: &apos; + vars.get(&apos;file_&apos; + n))
}

// this would be paging logic with startFrom as well as endWith
vars.put(&apos;startFrom&apos;, String.valueOf(ctx.getThreadNum() + 2)) </stringProp>
        </JSR223Sampler>
        <hashTree/>
        <ForeachController guiclass="ForeachControlPanel" testclass="ForeachController" testname="ForEach Controller" enabled="true">
          <stringProp name="ForeachController.inputVal">file</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="ForeachController.returnVal">currentFile</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="ForeachController.useSeparator">true</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="ForeachController.startIndex">${startFrom}</stringProp>
        </ForeachController>
        <hashTree>
          <DebugSampler guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="DebugSampler" testname="Print debug values" enabled="true">
            <boolProp name="displayJMeterProperties">true</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="displayJMeterVariables">true</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="displaySystemProperties">false</boolProp>
          </DebugSampler>
          <hashTree/>
          <JSR223Sampler guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="JSR223Sampler" testname="JSR223 Sampler" enabled="true">
            <stringProp name="scriptLanguage">groovy</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="parameters"></stringProp>
            <stringProp name="filename"></stringProp>
            <stringProp name="cacheKey">true</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="script">log.info(&apos;Copying file: &apos; + vars.get(&apos;currentFile&apos;))</stringProp>
          </JSR223Sampler>
          <hashTree/>
        </hashTree>
        <ResultCollector guiclass="ViewResultsFullVisualizer" testclass="ResultCollector" testname="View Results Tree" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="ResultCollector.error_logging">false</boolProp>
          <objProp>
            <name>saveConfig</name>
            <value class="SampleSaveConfiguration">
              <time>true</time>
              <latency>true</latency>
              <timestamp>true</timestamp>
              <success>true</success>
              <label>true</label>
              <code>true</code>
              <message>true</message>
              <threadName>true</threadName>
              <dataType>true</dataType>
              <encoding>false</encoding>
              <assertions>true</assertions>
              <subresults>true</subresults>
              <responseData>false</responseData>
              <samplerData>false</samplerData>
              <xml>false</xml>
              <fieldNames>true</fieldNames>
              <responseHeaders>false</responseHeaders>
              <requestHeaders>false</requestHeaders>
              <responseDataOnError>false</responseDataOnError>
              <saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>true</saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>
              <assertionsResultsToSave>0</assertionsResultsToSave>
              <bytes>true</bytes>
              <sentBytes>true</sentBytes>
              <url>true</url>
              <threadCounts>true</threadCounts>
              <idleTime>true</idleTime>
              <connectTime>true</connectTime>
            </value>
          </objProp>
          <stringProp name="filename"></stringProp>
        </ResultCollector>
        <hashTree/>
      </hashTree>
    </hashTree>
  </hashTree>
</jmeterTestPlan>
```

Why is each thread showing in log that it is copying each file when debug shows different `startFrom` values? I am most likely misusing something, but what?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your issue:

1. Assuming the following [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) defined:

   ```
   foo_2=bar
   foo_3=baz
   foo_4=qux
   ```
2. And the following [ForEach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) configuration

   [image]
3. JMeter starts with the offset specified by the [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) function, to wit:

   - user 1 iterates **all** variables
   - user 2 iterates **only the 2nd and the 3rd** variable
   - user 3 gets **only 3rd** variable

     [image]

Assuming all above:

- Either your understanding of how ForEach Controller works is not correct
- Or your `${startFrom}` variable value is the same for all threads, you can double check it using the [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler)

---

Also be aware of [Directory Listing Config](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-directory-listing-config-plugin-jmeter) plugin, if you need to conditionally iterate through files in a folder - it might be much easier to use.

Comment: What I am trying to do is actually the following: fetch all files from FTP in one thread, then split files into batches so each thread pulls equal amount of those files I fetched in that one thread. I will add a short edit showing my problem. It is pretty bad since this is my second/third time using JMeter...